# Convert LotusNotes datetime to C# DateTime format

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

Im using **interop.domino.dll** to extract LotusNotes schemas from domino database. Now the problem is inside the schema I'm getting datetime in the following format
**20150323T012130,00-08** which is not convertible to C# DateTime. It will be a great help if someone provide me some input on this.

Comment: What is `-08` part exactly?

Comment: Can't you split the string and create a new DateTime object?

Comment: Are you actually getting it as a string or some other type that just happens to *format as a string* to that value?

Comment: That's an ISO-8601 date format.  See the info on this page, in the section labled "Round Trip".  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
string str = "20150323T012130,01-08";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddTHHmmss,ffzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that the time will be in your "local" time, that if it is different than GMT-08, will be "different" from the one in the string.

This if you want to see the DateTime in Universal Time (GMT time)

```
var date2 = date.ToUniversalTime();
```

If you want to maintain the GMT offset, you have to use `DateTimeOffset`:

```
var date = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddTHHmmss,ffzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```